# Hadoop result is messed up

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Hadoop newbie here.
I want to count the co-ocurrence of words per line in a text, as in how many times a word appears in the same line with other words.
For that, I created a special class of word pairs, so MapReduce will give me the pair of words, and then the count. The thing is, the result is messed up, and I don't know where I'm wrong.

My word pair class is like this:

```
public class Par implements Writable,WritableComparable<Par> {

    public String palabra;
    public String vecino;

    public Par(String palabra, String vecino) {
        this.palabra = palabra;
        this.vecino = vecino;
    }

    public Par() {
        this.palabra = new String();
        this.vecino = new String();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Par otra) {
        int retorno = this.palabra.compareTo(otra.palabra);
        if(retorno != 0){
            return retorno;
        }
        return this.vecino.compareTo(otra.vecino);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeUTF(palabra);
         out.writeUTF(vecino);
    }

    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
        palabra = in.readUTF();
        vecino = in.readUTF();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((palabra == null) ? 0 : palabra.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((vecino == null) ? 0 : vecino.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Par other = (Par) obj;
        if (palabra == null) {
            if (other.palabra != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!palabra.equals(other.palabra))
            return false;
        if (vecino == null) {
            if (other.vecino != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!vecino.equals(other.vecino))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Par [" + palabra + " , " + vecino + "]";
    }


}
```

My mapper is:

```
public class Co_OcurrenciaMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Par, IntWritable> {
    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        String[] palabras = value.toString().split("\\s+");
        if (palabras.length > 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < palabras.length - 1; i++) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < palabras.length; j++) {
                    context.write(new Par(palabras[i], palabras[j]), one);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the result I get with MapReduce is:

```
[cloudera@quickstart Desktop]$ hadoop fs -cat salidaO11/part-r-00000 |head -15
Par [ , &c.]    35
Par [ , &c.']   2
Par [ , &c.,]   4
Par [ , &c]]    23
Par [ , ']  6
Par [ , ''Od's] 1
Par [ , ''Tis]  2
Par [ , ''tis]  1
Par [ , ''twas] 1
Par [ , '--O]   1
Par [ , 'A] 17
Par [ , 'ARTEMIDORUS.'] 1
Par [ , 'Above] 1
Par [ , 'Achilles]  2
Par [ , 'Ad]    3
cat: Unable to write to output stream.
```

Where am I wrong? A friend suggested toconcatenate the two words into a single String, but I think it is not that elegant.

Comment: Since the question has been answered, I hope you are looking into MR just to know how it works. Otherwise you should be looking at Spark. This whole job can be written in 3 lines of code: `val input = sc.textFile("s3://...")
val words = input.flatMap(x => x.split(" "))
val result = words.map(x => (x, 1)).reduceByKey((x, y) => x + y)`

Comment: Exactly, I am learning MapReduce, so this is more of a practice thing than something for production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think anything is wrong here. You don't appear to have any data cleansing, so I think it's fair that it would produce dirty output like that.

You might want to try writing some MRUnit tests, or feeding some smaller, cleaner datasets into the job to confirm that it does what you expect?

Comment: The text file is perfectly clean. I already used it for other MapReduce tasks without any problems. I will write the MRUnit tests, though. Thanks!